# Using RegExp to loop through arrays instead of for loops (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have the below code which works. But would using RegExp be a more efficient code?

(Return true if the string in the first element of the array contains the letters of the string in the second element of the array.)

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var first = arr[0].split("");
  var second = arr[1].split("");
  var answer = false;
  for (var e = 0; e < second.length; e++) {
    answer = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
      if (first[i] === second[e]) {
        answer = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return answer;
}

mutation(['hello', 'hey']);
```

Comment: The only match that matters in your code is the last character of the second string, because you set `answer` back to `false` before each letter.

Comment: RegEx would certainly be more elegant I'm not sure about efficiency though

Comment: Are you allowed to use ES6 collections?

Comment: @Pointy thanks for pointing that out. I guess I will have to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex to do this check as the code you've shown above:

```
var a = 'hello how are you';
var b ='hey you there';

var result = new RegExp(b.split(/ +/)[0].split('').join('|')).test( a.split(/ +/)[0] );
//=> true
```

- First `split(/ +/)[0]` is used to get first word from both strings
- Then `split('')` is used to get each letter from first word of 2nd input
- `join('|')` is used to join them by `|` to get regex as `h|e|y`
- `new RegExp` is used for construct a regex object
- `test` is used to execute the regex

Comment: Thank you for this and the detailed explanation. It seems so much more elegant than the double for loops.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 it can be written as follows:

```
function mutation(lettersSource, checkedString) {
   var referenceLetters = new Set(lettersSource); // get letters from string
   var usedLetters = new Set(checkedString);
   // create union of letters in both strings
   var lettersUnion = new Set([...usedLetters, ...referenceLetters]);
   return lettersUnion.size === referenceLetters.size;
}
```

This solution is `O(m+n+k)` where `m` and `n` is number of letters in strings, and `k` is number of used letters.

Your solution is `O(m*n)`, quite inefficient.

In ES5 `Object` can be used as well as dictionary to collect only letters, but it will be slower for many possible letters (Unicode strings).

If you don't have to care about memory usage, you can create dense array using `.charCodeAt` to index elements in array for O(1) access to checking if elements exists (`O(m+n+k)`).